# JSONPath extract string "where" JSON file

Tags: json, xpath, jsonpath

I'm trying to run JSONPath on the below json file and extract all the IP Addresses (ip_prefix:) where the region equals "region: "ap-southeast-1""

https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json

My xpath skills are rusty, my JSONPath skills are novice!

Comment: Show what you have tried and we can tell you what you are doing wrong. [This page](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) lists an example a lot like what you want: `$..book[?(@.price<10)] ` "filter all books cheaper than 10"

Comment: Thanks, I got it working $.prefixes[?(@.region=="ap-southeast-2")].ip_prefix

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it with guidance from the blog post samples ...

```
$.prefixes[?(@.region=="ap-southeast-2")].ip_prefix
```